# Recyclerview to busy and crashes

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I often get the error "Cannot call this method while RecyclerView is computing a layout or scrolling". I think this is caused by having 5 fragments creating an recyclerview at the same time. I could fix it by setting the viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit to 2, but that is not quitte the solution as I'm using threads and can't afford to get an tab out of focus.

I was think about adding fragments, with a slight time delay, but failed to do so. Anyone knows how to fix it?

Solution, but not optimal for me due to threads: `viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2);`

My onload and public class:

```
Public class MainActivity {
    static MainActivity main;
    Toolbar toolbar;
    TabLayout tabLayout;
    ViewPager viewPager;
    ViewPagerAdapter viewPagerAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolBar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
    viewPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    viewPagerAdapter.addFragments(new Maandag_home(), "MA");
    viewPagerAdapter.addFragments(new Dinsdag_home(), "DI");
    viewPagerAdapter.addFragments(new Woensdag_home(), "WO");
    viewPagerAdapter.addFragments(new Donderdag_home(), "DO");
    viewPagerAdapter.addFragments(new Vrijdag_home(), "VR");
    viewPager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
}
```

Viewpager adapter code:

```
package com.mycompany.myapp;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

ArrayList<Fragment> fragments = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> tabTitles = new ArrayList<>();

public void addFragments(Fragment fragments, String titles)
{
    this.fragments.add(fragments);
    this.tabTitles.add(titles);
}

public ViewPagerAdapter (FragmentManager fm)
{
    super(fm);
}
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return fragments.get(position);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return fragments.size();
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    return tabTitles.get(position);
}
}
```

Recyclerview adapter:

```
package com.mycompany.myapp;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.support.v7.widget.CardView;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MyRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView
    .Adapter<MyRecyclerViewAdapter
    .DataObjectHolder> {
private static String LOG_TAG = "MyRecyclerViewAdapter";
private ArrayList<DataObject> mDataset;
private static MyClickListener myClickListener;

public static class DataObjectHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
        implements View
        .OnClickListener {
    TextView label;
    TextView dateTime;
    TextView tijd;
    CardView cardView;

    public DataObjectHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        label = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        dateTime = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        tijd = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        cardView = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_view);
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Adding Listener");
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        myClickListener.onItemClick(getAdapterPosition(), v);
    }
}

public void setOnItemClickListener(MyClickListener myClickListener) {
    this.myClickListener = myClickListener;
}

public MyRecyclerViewAdapter(ArrayList<DataObject> myDataset) {
    mDataset = myDataset;
}

@Override
public DataObjectHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                           int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.card_view_row, parent, false);

    DataObjectHolder dataObjectHolder = new DataObjectHolder(view);
    return dataObjectHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(DataObjectHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.label.setText(mDataset.get(position).getmText1());
    holder.dateTime.setText(mDataset.get(position).getmText2());
    holder.tijd.setText(mDataset.get(position).getmText3());
    String color = mDataset.get(position).getmState();
    if (color == "FFFFFF") {}
    else if (color == "F44336") {
        holder.cardView.setCardBackgroundColor(0xFFF44336);
        holder.label.setTextColor(0xFFFFFFFF);
        holder.dateTime.setTextColor(0xFFFFFFFF);
    }
    else if (color == "4CAF50"){
        holder.cardView.setCardBackgroundColor(0xFF4CAF50);
        holder.label.setTextColor(0xFFFFFFFF);
        holder.dateTime.setTextColor(0xFFFFFFFF);
    }
    else if (color == "FFEB3B") {
        holder.cardView.setCardBackgroundColor(0xFFFFEB3B);
    }
    else if (color == "607D8B") {
        holder.cardView.setCardBackgroundColor(0xFF607D8B);
    }
}

public void addItem(DataObject dataObj, int index) {
    mDataset.add(index, dataObj);
    notifyItemInserted(index);
}

public void deleteItem(int index) {
    mDataset.remove(index);
    notifyItemRemoved(index);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mDataset.size();
}

public interface MyClickListener {
    public void onItemClick(int position, View v);
}
}
```

How I add items (cards) to the recyclerview programatically:

```
DataObject obj = new DataObject("My Subject", "My Teacher", "Time", "FFFFFF");
((MyRecyclerViewAdapter) mAdapter).addItem(obj, index);
```

Error when running with `viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(4)`

FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-7997
    Process: com.mycompany.myapp, PID: 21990
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call this method while RecyclerView is computing a layout or scrolling
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.assertNotInLayoutOrScroll(RecyclerView.java:2186)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$RecyclerViewDataObserver.onItemRangeInserted(RecyclerView.java:4281)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$AdapterDataObservable.notifyItemRangeInserted(RecyclerView.java:9969)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.notifyItemInserted(RecyclerView.java:5856)
    at com.mycompany.myapp.MyRecyclerViewAdapter.addItem(MyRecyclerViewAdapter.java:89)
    at com.mycompany.myapp.Maandag_home$2.run(Maandag_home.java:174)

I think I've given enough information, if not please comment instead of immediately downvoting. I searched through the internet quitte a lot, even asked a Java developer, but he and the internet just didn't know.

**PS: I'm wondering if the title is wrong, please correct it if it is**

Comment: post `ViewPagerAdapter` code here.

Comment: @Ironman added now

Comment: you are right you are created `5 Fragment` that's why it load too much So i suggest you to use `Handler` for that. It can solve your problem.

Comment: show code for adding items to your list

Comment: can you please add your recycler view adapter code? thanks.

Comment: @savepopulation added

Comment: I think also the Maandag_home class would be good to post so we can see Maandag_home$2.run

Comment: How could you have 5 fragments creating an recyclerview at the same time? I believe that each fragment has its own view ?

Comment: @TinTran Maybe because they all use Recyclerviewadapter and my DataObject (it puts the data into the card) at the same time

Comment: whats in com.mycompany.myapp.Maandag_home$2.run(Maandag_home.java:174) ?  are you trying for pagination?

Comment: @NIPHIN I'm doing this on line 174: I am adding the items to the recyclerview: `DataObject obj = new DataObject("My Subject", "My Teacher", "Time", "FFFFFF");
((MyRecyclerViewAdapter) mAdapter).addItem(obj, index);`

Comment: The root cause is that the list is scrolling while you are adding an item causing an illegalstateexception. and try to populateview in onViewCreated of your fragment so that the fragment has finished layouting its children and the child recyclerview would have already completed is layouting. And before you add item check if recycler view is scrolling

Comment: So 5 fragments have 5 recyclerView which shared the same Adapter ?

Comment: Can you post this block com.mycompany.myapp.Maandag_home$2.run(Maandag_home.java:174)
?
Are you calling addItem from other thread or a handler ?

Comment: @TinTran oncreate I am calling an thread. The thread gets an array from the server, I sort the array in the good category by if statements and then I'll call addItem to add it as an card. I cannot share it, as it has confidential information, its way too big and I don't like my code to be online

Comment: @TinTran: do you suspect the exception is raised due to adding item from a background thread?

Comment: there is no problem with adding item from a background thread. It is though when you call notify* on the adapter from a background thread

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1/ 
Change this:

```
public MyRecyclerViewAdapter(ArrayList<DataObject> myDataset) {
    mDataset = myDataset;
}
```

to this:

// get Activity from the fragment with getActivity() and pass to constructor

```
public MyRecyclerViewAdapter(Activity activity, ArrayList<DataObject> myDataset) {
     mDataset = myDataset;
     mActivity = activity;
}
```

2/ 
Change this:

```
public void addItem(DataObject dataObj, int index) {
    mDataset.add(index, dataObj);
    notifyItemInserted(index);
}
```

to this:

```
public void addItem(DataObject dataObj, final int index) { 
    if (mActivity == null){ 
    return; 
} 

mActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() { 
    @Override public void run() { 
        mDataset.add(index, dataObj); 
       notifyItemInserted(index); 
    } 
}); 
}
```

// comment: The reason of the crash is you update the data set from a background thread. You could even change to an AsyncTask to archive even a prettier implementation.

Comment: Here is the code of my Maandag_home. Please, comment when you clicked the link, so I can remove the paste, as I don't want it to be public.

Comment: I don't know how to implement your answer, that why I'm sharing the code :)

Comment: I have got it. Wrap every calls to adapter.notify* to activity.runonUiThread() from the run method of your Thread. will solve it.

Comment: There is no call to adapter.notify , except in the MyRecyclerViewAdapter.java

Comment: I mean every calls that leads to adapter.notify*. for instance adapter.addItem

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115034/discussion-between-tintran-and-jason).

Answer (score 0):

I think there's a problem about you `RecyclerViewAdapter` implementation.

I did not see how you add items to your recycler view but you every time add an object to your list (ArrayList myDataset) you notify your adapter with addItem method.

```
public void addItem(DataObject dataObj, int index) {
    mDataset.add(index, dataObj);
    notifyItemInserted(index);
}
```

When you get data from server (i assume you are fetching your data from a web api) you can add your data to array list which you bind with your adapter and then notify once like below for initial process.

```
List<DataObject> mDataSet = yourAdapter.getDataSet();
mDataSet.addAll(yourServerDataObjectList);
yourAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Later you can call `notifyItemInserted` if you insert a new item or `notifyItemRangeChanged` if a set of items added or removed.

You should do this init operation change for every fragment which you put to your view pager.

I hope this'll help you.

Good Luck!

Edit:

I assume you have 5 fragments and in every fragment you have separated recycler views, separated data lists and separated api calls to receive data and you receive data from api on a callback.

Change `ArrayList` to `List`

```
private List<DataObject> mDataset;
```

Change your constructor:

```
public MyRecyclerViewAdapter(List<DataObject> myDataset) {
            mDataset = myDataset;
        }
```

Create a fresh `List` and your Adapter like below:

```
List<DataObject>myDataSet = new ArrayList<>();
MyRecyclerViewAdapter mAdapter = new MyRecyclerViewAdapter(myDataSet);
```

When you receive data from api:

```
@Override
public void onDataReceived(List<DataObject> data) {
    // Do your sort or clean data.
    myDataSet.addAll(data);
    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();                    
}
```

Comment: I prefer not to save it in an array list, as I'm looping it through if loops and that kind of stuff.

Comment: my point is if you are adding all your items which you received from server one by one with your addItem method you face this issue. i don't know how you init your data. if you can put your code maybe i can help you more.

Comment: I am getting it through an api, then I sort it with if statements to give it the category where it is supposed to go. Should I put some code after every if statement that saves the data in an array list? if so, how can I do that because I never quitte used an array list

Comment: Could you maybe tell me in what file I should put it? Should I put it all in Maandag_home, MyRecyclerViewAdapter, pieces in both or what? I tried to merge it with my current code but that won't work, mainly because I don't know in which files I should put it

Comment: In every fragment which you add to view pager you should have separate rcyclerviews, adapters and if needed api calls. every fragment should manage it's own process.